# How to pass array to constructor and save in class variable

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, class-variables

I have the following peace of code of a Satellite

```
class Satellite
{
private:
    const static int CHIP_SEQ_LENGTH = 1023;
    bool chipSequence[CHIP_SEQ_LENGTH];
    int id;

public:
    Satellite(int id, bool chipSequence[])
    {
        this->id = id;
        this->chipSequence = chipSequence;
    };
}
```

I get an error at

```
this->chipSequence = chipSequence;
```

with the following description:

```
Expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
```

Now my question is, how to store an array passed by the constructor into a class variable?

Comment: I suggest to use `std::bitset` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in arrays are nasty things that don't behave like most C++ objects. In particular, they aren't assignable.

In modern C++, I'd probably use `std::array<bool, CHIP_SEQ_LENGTH>`. This is a proper copyable object type.

If you're stuck in the past, you could make your own copyable wrapper type:

```
struct ChipSequence {
    bool bits[CHIP_SEQ_LENGTH];
};
```

or explicitly copy the data:

```
std::copy(chipSequence, chipSequence+CHIP_SEQ_LENGTH, this->chipSequence);
```

There are also alternatives like `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`, which pack the bits to use less memory, if you don't specifically need an array of `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You must note that the name of array is a pointer to the first node of the array,so when you write the below code, you will drop the array in memory and waste it.

```
this->chipSequence = chipSequence;
```

Actually, the simple way is to create a `for` loop for copy nodes one by one from source to destination.